# Javascript setdate getDate()+28 returns bad

Tags: javascript

I am getting a weird output when trying to add days to a date value.

```
var startdate = $("#JobStartDate").val();

startdate = new Date(startdate);
startdate28 = startdate.setDate(startdate.getDate()+28);

console.log(startdate);
console.log(startdate28);
```

results in

```
startdate = "Date 2017-03-15T00:00:00.000Z"

startdate28 = 1489536000000
```

any ideas where i am going wrong?

Comment: `startdate.getDate()+28` will get you the time in milliseconds + 28

Comment: To be more precise, `setDate` returns milliseconds, but also sets the date *in place*

Comment: [`setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) changes the underlying date object in-place and then returns the milliseconds since 01.01.1970 UTC

Comment: people start using moment.js :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like so:

```
var startdate = $("#JobStartDate").val();

startdate = new Date(startdate);
startdate28 = new Date();
startdate28.setDate(startdate.getDate()+28);

console.log(startdate);
console.log(startdate28);
```

Answer (score 1):

for this line: startdate28 = startdate.setDate(startdate.getDate()+28);
You store what returns from "startdate.setDate" inside "startdate28" and this function return the time stamp for the adjusted date.

What you can do is to create a new date object for the other date:

```
var startdate = '2016-01-01';

startdate = new Date(startdate);
startdate28 = new Date(startdate.setDate(startdate.getDate()+28));

console.log(startdate);
console.log(startdate28);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following code snippet:

```js
var startdate = "2017-02-15";

startdate = new Date(startdate);
startdate28 = new Date();
startdate28.setTime(startdate.getTime() + 28 * 86400000);

console.log(startdate);
console.log(startdate28);
```

Notice that you need to us `setTime` intead of `setDate` as that may cause errors when the month or year isn't the same as the one before adding the days.

The result will be:

> "2017-02-15T00:00:00.000Z"
>
> "2017-03-15T00:00:00.000Z"

Answer (score 0):

the method Date.getDate() results in an integer. So, integer+28 is still an integer and not a Date type. Try:

```
var startdate;
startdate = new Date("2017-03-15T00:00:00.000Z"); 
startdate28 = new Date();
startdate28.setDate(startdate.getDate()+28);
console.log(startdate); 
console.log(startdate28);
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
addDays = function(days) {
    var startdate = new Date(this.valueOf());
    startdate.setDate(startdate.getDate() + days);
    return startdate;
}

var startdate= new Date();

alert(dat.addDays(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution I've found is as followed:

```
var startdate = "2017-02-15";
startdate = new Date(startdate);
startdate28 = new Date(startdate.setDate(startdate.getDate()+28));
```